# Can't login after removing tmux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, tmux

I'm on xubuntu 16.10. Just ran `sudo apt remove tmux` and it removed the package successfully.

Problem is, as soon as I try opening any terminal it just disappears.

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to get a barebones terminal, enter login and password, but it just starts over by asking login and password again with no chance of getting in.

How can I take control of my shell again?

---

EDIT: I can boot the machine and use Xfce normally. I just can't open any terminal. So I guess I need to find a way to debug and fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have some reference to tmux in `~/.bashrc` or whatever.

Try running xfce-terminal as follows:

```
xfce4-terminal -e "bash --norc --noprofile" --hold
```

Because `$PS1` is not set, you may not see a prompt. Simple set one:

```
export PS1="\h:\W \u\$ "
```

Just remember: Because you skipped all shell initialization, some things may not behave as expected. Like `$PATH` not containing everything/anything.

From the shell that is now working, fix the issues with your login scripts.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this pointed me to the right direction. My problem specifically was tmux-zen assuming the presence of tmux. Removing the references to it on init files fixed the issue.